# Unpredictable random number unique in table in MariaDB (not just incremental)

Tags: mysql, random, mariadb

I have table of `Users` in MariaDB and I need to generate `serviceNumber` for each newly created user.

Example of this code: `865165`

Only two requirements are:

- Unique in `User` table
- Unpredictable when creating user (Not based on AutoIncrement maybe?)

Is this possible with just database? Or I need to implement it in backend when creating user.

Comment: As far as MySQL is concerned I think cryptographically random number generation is only available on MySQL 8.0+. You can of course write your own User Defined Function.

Comment: Which version of MySQL / MariaDB are you running?

Answer (score 2):

The only (theoretically) collision free solution would be to generate the serviceNumber with `UUID()` function (or maybe  `UUID_SHORT()`).

The disadvantage of this solution is, that it can't be used in statement based replication, in this case you should create the value in your backend.

Answer (score 1):

Steps 1-3 are setup steps:

1. Decide on how big you want the numbers to be.  6-digit numbers would let you have a million numbers.
2. Build a temp table `t` with all 6-digit numbers (`t_num`).
3. Build and populate a permanent table:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `u` (
       id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
       t_num INT NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY(id)
   );
   INSERT INTO u (t_num)
       SELECT t_num FROM t ORDER BY RAND();
   ```

4--Plan A  You have an auto_inc id in the real table; simply join to `u` to get the random 6-digit number.

4--Plan B

```
    BEGIN;
    SELECT t_num FROM u ORDER BY id LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;  -- to get the random id
    DELETE FROM u ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;   -- Remove it from the list of available ids
```

Answer (score 0):

From MySQL reference manual:

> To obtain a random integer R in the range i <= R < j, use the
>   expression FLOOR(i + RAND() * (j − i)). For example, to obtain a
>   random integer in the range the range 7 <= R < 12, use the following
>   statement:
>   `SELECT FLOOR(7 + (RAND() * 5));`

Make the field holding `serviceNumber` uniqe and use the above math expression to generate serviceNumbers.

Comment: Using rand() is not collision free.